# Unable to rebuild index in django haystack

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am trying to run manage.py rebuild_index but getting below error.

```
`(django_project)deep@deep-ThinkPad-Edge:~/doroko$ python manage.py rebuild_index No handlers could be found for logger "django_facebook.models" /home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/image.py:150: RemovedInDjango18Warning: Support for the PIL will be removed in Django 1.8. Please uninstall it & install Pillow instead.   RemovedInDjango18Warning

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS: ?: (1_6.W001) Some project unittests may not execute as expected.     HINT: Django 1.6 introduced a new default test runner. It looks like this project was generated using Django 1.5 or earlier. You should ensure your tests are all running & behaving as expected. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#new-test-runner for more information. System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS: ?: (1_6.W001) Some project unittests may not execute as expected.     HINT: Django 1.6 introduced a new default test runner. It looks like this project was generated using Django 1.5 or earlier. You should ensure your tests are all running & behaving as expected. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#new-test-runner for more information.

WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index in connection 'default'. Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command. Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y Removing all documents from your index because you said so. Failed to clear Elasticsearch index: ConnectionError(('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))) caused by: ProtocolError(('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))) All documents removed. System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS: ?: (1_6.W001) Some project unittests may not execute as expected.     HINT: Django 1.6 introduced a new default test runner. It looks like this project was generated using Django 1.5 or earlier. You should ensure your tests are all running & behaving as expected. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#new-test-runner for more information. Indexing 34 wishs ERROR:root:Error updating feed using default  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 189, in handle_label
    self.update_backend(label, using)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 234, in update_backend
    do_update(backend, index, qs, start, end, total, self.verbosity)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 89, in do_update
    backend.update(index, current_qs)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py", line 164, in update
    prepped_data = index.full_prepare(obj)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/indexes.py", line 207, in full_prepare
    self.prepared_data = self.prepare(obj)   File "/home/deep/doroko/feed/search_indexes.py", line 16, in prepare
    data = super(feedIndex, self).prepare(obj)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/indexes.py", line 198, in prepare
    self.prepared_data[field.index_fieldname] = field.prepare(obj)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/fields.py", line 159, in prepare
    return self.convert(super(CharField, self).prepare(obj))   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/fields.py", line 165, in convert
    return six.text_type(value)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 81, in __str__
    in opts.concrete_managers + opts.abstract_managers StopIteration Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/rebuild_index.py", line 16, in handle
    call_command('update_index', **options)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 115, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 184, in handle
    return super(Command, self).handle(*items, **options)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 503, in handle
    label_output = self.handle_label(label, **options)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 189, in handle_label
    self.update_backend(label, using)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 234, in update_backend
    do_update(backend, index, qs, start, end, total, self.verbosity)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 89, in do_update
    backend.update(index, current_qs)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py", line 164, in update
    prepped_data = index.full_prepare(obj)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/indexes.py", line 207, in full_prepare
    self.prepared_data = self.prepare(obj)   File "/home/deep/doroko/feed/search_indexes.py", line 16, in prepare
    data = super(feedIndex, self).prepare(obj)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/indexes.py", line 198, in prepare
    self.prepared_data[field.index_fieldname] = field.prepare(obj)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/fields.py", line 159, in prepare
    return self.convert(super(CharField, self).prepare(obj))   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/fields.py", line 165, in convert
    return six.text_type(value)   File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 81, in __str__
    in opts.concrete_managers + opts.abstract_managers StopIteration`
```

This is the search_indexes.py file for model.

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from feed.models import Wish

class feedIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    wish_text = indexes.CharField(model_attr='wish_text',null=True)
    tags = indexes.CharField(model_attr='tags')
    added = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='added')

    def get_model(self):
        return Wish
    def prepare_wish_text(self, obj):
        return "Wish"
    def prepare(self, obj):
        data = super(feedIndex, self).prepare(obj)
        data["_boost"] = 1.5
        return data
```

Following are versions used :

```
Django==1.7.6
django-haystack==2.3.1
elasticsearch==1.4.0
pyelasticsearch==0.5
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Testing seems to suggest this comes up if a search template is incorrectly configured.

Double check all the fields in your search template and find the incorrect one and the issue should resolve.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-haystack/InXrimOyHtQ